# Nasm method to accept input

Tags: assembly, nasm

Is it possible in nasm to accept input from user without using ebx & ecx registers ? if yes please suggest me possible ways....
I tried the method

```
mov eax,3
mov ebx,2
mov ecx,n
int 80h
```

Comment: _"without using ebx & ecx registers ?"_ Why do you need that?  Also, surely you mean `int 80h` or `int 0x80`?

Comment: What's wrong with saving them on the stack?

Comment: Could push parameters and call `read()`... or scanf. I don't think there's any way using `int 80h`.

Comment: Michael thanks for your comment. I know that the way I tried is best enough. but, still I found program which is accepting the same using esi & edi. So,  I want to know about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always wrap your code with some relevant push instructions.

```
push eax ; keep registers.
push ebx
push ecx

mov eax,3
mov ebx,2
mov ecx,n
int 80h

pop ecx ; restore registers.
pop ebx
pop eax
```

This way you don't change eax,ebx or ecx.
Though I don't think you should really care about changing those registers. This is what they are for.